# How to specify root username on docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file working fine. I want to have a user that has root privileges, so that i can access the database from outside using that user instead of the root one. I can do it after i create te container, but i´d like to automatize it so that a new user with privileges is created or i can change the root name.

```
    version: '3.8'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: 'palc'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'palc'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'palc'
      MYSQL_USER: 'palc'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'palc'
    volumes:
      - .:/palc/var/lib/mysql

  palc:
    image: palc
    container_name: palc
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: bash -c " python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/palc
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

Comment: Is this about a database user or an OS user?  You can already access the database from outside the container (`mysql -h localhost -P 3307`).  What's a command you might like to run that doesn't have the behavior you expect?

Comment: have you try to mount a script in a volume to automate the commands you want ?

Comment: I indeed can access the database, I´d like to do exactly what [Dedey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15478830/dedey) is mentioning. I want my docker-compose to create a mysql container that has a customized user with root privileges so that i do not need to use the root one. Every new contributor that creates the container should have that user too

Comment: Something similar as running a command on the docker-compose, but I only want to run it once since im creating a user